# Remove objects using NSPredicate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdictionary, nspredicate

I have the folloving dictionary which has many sub dictionaries.
How can I remove objects where `isChanged = 1` from parent dictionary using `NSPredicate`?

```
{
    "0_496447097042228" =     {
        cellHeight = 437;
        isChanged = 1;
    };
    "100000019882803_193629104095337" =     {
        cellHeight = 145;
        isChanged = 0;
    };
    "100002140902243_561833243831980" =     {
        cellHeight = 114;
        isChanged = 1;
    };
    "100004324964792_129813607172804" =     {
        cellHeight = 112;
        isChanged = 0;
    };
    "100004324964792_129818217172343" =     {
        cellHeight = 127;
        isChanged = 0;
    };
    "100004324964792_129835247170640" =     {
        cellHeight = 127;
        isChanged = 1;
    };
}
```

Comment: what happen with your problem..?

Comment: ok brother then accept his answer and +1 and my code will work too if you have data in that format

Comment: @Rajneesh071 below I added my solutions as answer

Comment: great work....your answer is combination of both answer..nice..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem in the following way:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isChanged == %d", 1];

NSArray *allObjs = [parentDict.allValues filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

[allObjs enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSMutableArray *keys = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    [keys setArray:[parentDict allKeysForObject:obj]];
    [parentDict removeObjectsForKeys:keys];
    [keys release];
}];
```

Answer (score 4):

As a simple alternative to using NSPredicate, you can use the NSDictionary's built in `keysOfEntriesPassingTest:`  This answer assumes "isChanged" is an NSString and the value 0 or 1 is an NSNumber:

```
NSSet *theSet = [dict keysOfEntriesPassingTest:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    return [obj[@"isChanged"] isEqualToNumber: @1];
}];
```

The returned set is a list of keys that pass the test.  From there, you could remove all that matched with:

`[dict removeObjectsForKeys:[theSet allObjects]];`

Comment: The code in the block can be simplified to just : return [obj[@"isChanged"] isEqual: @1]; There's no need for the if-else clause.

Comment: You don't need to avoid literals for iOS<=5, because that's backward compatible to iOS4 as you can see here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ObjCAvailabilityIndex/_index.html and the block based filtering method that you have used is available from iOS4 onwards - so writing two methods isn't needed.

Comment: I was going to leave the verbose answer for clarity, but I think you're right @rdelmar, it's pretty clear even without the clause.

Comment: @JShapiro Finally - sorry to be picky - but the comparison should really be done with `isEqualToNumber:` It's better to be explicit with object comparisons, even though lower valued NSNumbers are singletons, that is an implementation detail that shouldn't be relied upon.

Comment: @Abizern I appreciate you being picky :)  Editing answer.

Answer (score 0):

when you have array of dictionary than you can remove selected category's data using NSPredicate

here is code

```
NSString *selectedCategory = @"1";

//filter array by category using predicate
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isChanged == %@", selectedCategory];

NSArray *filteredArray = [yourAry filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

[yourAry removeObject:[filteredArray objectAtIndex:0]];
```

But in your problem data is not in array it is in dictionary

your data should be in this format

```
(
 {
     cellHeight = 437;
     isChanged = 1;
 },
 {
     cellHeight = 145;
     isChanged = 0;
 },
 {
     cellHeight = 114;
     isChanged = 1;
 }
 )
```