# Issue with fetching data from db file using NSPredicate

Tags: iphone, nspredicate

i have two NSManagedObject classes, UserInfo and Department (to-one and to-many relationship respectively )here is my code,

// UserInfo.h

```
@interface UserInfo : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * bDate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * firstName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * lastName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * userName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Department *dept;

@end
```

//Department.h

```
@class UserInfo;

@interface Department : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * post;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * location;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *user;
@end

@interface Department (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addUserObject:(UserInfo *)value;
- (void)removeUserObject:(UserInfo *)value;
- (void)addUser:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeUser:(NSSet *)values;
@end
```

for searching particular user from db i used, which works well

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstName contains[cd] %@", NameTosearch];
```

but, now what kind of predicate i can use to fetch all users with info connected to particular department?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use a comparison with an object in predicates.

I.e. If you have a pointer to a Department instance in dept:

...withFormat:@"dept = %@", dept"

internally CoreData will replace the %@ with the managed object identifier of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Search using

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstName contains[cd] == %@", NameTosearch];
```

Follow this blog for more info [http://rajneesh071.blogspot.in/](http://rajneesh071.blogspot.in/2012/10/predicates.html)
And follow my answer [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13541371/remove-objects-using-nspredicate/13542899#13542899)